# How to determine Android GPU Clock?

Tags: android, gpu

It is possible to dynamically query an Android device for the current CPU clock similar to what is mentioned in what follows.

```
adb shell "cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq"
```

However, it seems like there is not a similar option for GPU. I was wondering if there is a way, anything, to do the same for GPUs. Any help is greatly appreciated.

(CPU/GPU frequencies are not good indicators of speed. I mainly need them for some study on DVFS)

Comment: why you not use http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/gpu-profiler

Comment: @aminsaffar Thanks Amin jan. I am running a large test case and need to measure the frequency the exact moment that I launch a kernel. However, it is not possible to synchronize the profiler with the kernel launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How I found the GPU freq and % for Android Galaxy S5 on OSX/Linux

1. Attach your phone for debugging.
2. In terminal: ./adb -s  shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger
3. Find the line with "GLES:"
4. The GPU name is there. For the galaxy s5 it is "Mali-T628"
5. ./adb shell find "/sys/" -type f
6. Search through and find the "mali" folder
7. use adb shell cat  to investigate what the files contain
8. Used ./adb shell cat /sys/devices/11800000.mali/utilization, which lists the gpu used % as an integer
9. Used ./adb shell cat /sys/devices/11800000.mali/clock, which lists the gpu freq as an integer
10. Use those integers in your perf reporting

Answer (score 0):

As Amin mentioned, the best solution is using the profiler. I used Android profiler ([like](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/gpu-profiler)) to measure the performance.